# Can you explain to me this code?

Tags: javascript

It is supposed to find Eric within the text, I get that, but can someone explain to me what the 'for' loops does? Thanks.

```
/*jshint multistr:true */

text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Eric \
blah blah blah Eric blah blah Eric blah blah \
blah blah blah blah blah Eric";

var myName = "Eric";
var hits = [];

for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === "E") {
        for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
            hits.push(text[j]);
        }
    }
}

if (hits.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't find Eric, it finds any substring that starts with E and has the same length. So Echo would work, for instance. To me, the code is nonsensical and should be deleted without further thought =/

Comment: Replacement code to find Eric: `if( text.indexOf(myName) > -1) console.log("Name found!");`

Comment: This will eric 16 times , because you iterating it hits.length and printing full word which is stored by hits if you want to print eric only four times so replace your code with this

var getLength=hits.length;

if (getLength === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
 for(var k=0;k<getLength;k++){
  document.write(hits[k]);
 }
}
 it will eric four times,Hope it will help for you

Answer (score 2):

High level this code checks every character looking for the string 'Eric'.  Specifically it is looking for the character 'E' and then the following 3 characters.  If it finds the character 'E' it will add it and the following 3 characters to an output array

```
// This is defining a test string
text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Eric \
blah blah blah Eric blah blah Eric blah blah \
blah blah blah blah blah Eric";

// A substring to search for
var myName = "Eric";

// An output array where the target string is stored once it is found
var hits = [];

// Look at every character inside the test string
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    // If the character is 'E'
    if (text[i] === "E") {
        // Add the character E and the following characters up to the length of the target string to the output
        for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
            hits.push(text[j]);
        }
    }
}

// If the output has elements than we have found our target string
if (hits.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your explanation here:

```
/* The \ here is used for the text going to the next line to be the same line. */

text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Eric \
blah blah blah Eric blah blah Eric blah blah \
blah blah blah blah blah Eric";

/* Variable Declaration of to be found. */

var myName = "Eric";
var hits = [];

/* Going through each and every character. */

for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    /* Checking if the current character is E */
    if (text[i] === "E") {
        /* If so, start from there, and check the next character in my name, "r". */
        for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
            hits.push(text[j]);
        }
    }
}

/* If this is empty, we didn't have your name in the text. */
if (hits.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

It just checks for Er I don't know why when if Er is found, it would return true. Wow. Oh wait, the second time when it checks, both `i` and `j` are incremented.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `for` statement iterates over the `text` string (over each letter):

   ```
   for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
   ```
2. If finds a letter 'E':

   ```
   if (text[i] === "E")
   ```
3. Runs a new loop with `myName` length to collect the next letters after the 'E':

   ```
   for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++)
   ```
4. Pushing each letter into the `hints` Array:

   ```
   hits.push(text[j]);
   ```
5. Finally checks if the name was found or not to display on the console:

   ```
   if (hits.length === 0) {
       console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
   } else {
       console.log(hits);
   }
   ```